# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) ProductList.js:14 Error fetching products: AxiosError fe

Tags: http-status-code-404

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAakx.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNg7U.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZUgf.png)
Why can't I connect to the backend? I hope someone can help me
The error '404 (Not Found)' occurs when a POST request to http://localhost:3000/products is not processed by the server because the corresponding route is not found on the server. This typically happens when the server does not have a POST route for '/products' defined or there is a mismatch in the definition of this route.
Please double-check your server-side code to ensure that the POST route '/products' is defined correctly and activated. Make sure that you have added this route using the POST method in your server code, and the server is running on port 3000.